# Influence of edge number and priority-queue implementation on the runtime of Dijkstra

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, graphs, runtime-analysis, shortest-path

When we try to find the shortest path of a directed weighted graph using Dijkstra’s algorithm, is there a relation between the number of edges/vertices of the graph and the different implementations of minimum priority queue that help us find out the running time of the algorithm?

Comment: What you are asking about is what is called _dense_ or _sparse_ graphs.  A graph is dense if there are many edges (say $\Omega(|V|^2)$).  A graph is sparse otherwise.  There was a question on SO with a good answer here: [Optimizing Dijkstra for dense graph?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413859/optimizing-dijkstra-for-dense-graph)

Comment: CLRS (Introduction to Algorithms), 3rd Edition, talks a little about how the priority queue affects the running time on page 662. If the graph is sparse ($E = o(V^2 / \log V)$), we can reduce the running time from $O(V^2)$ to $O((V+E)\log V)$ by using a binary min-heap to implement the priority queue. We can improve the runtime on any graph by using a Fibonacci heap.